# Using Apache RedirectMatch in an SSL Vhost

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, mod-proxy

I would like to:

- redirect https requests for `/` to `/sweetApp/`
- redirect all http requests to https
- after the redirects, proxy requests to an internal ip address

I have set up these vhost rules. The http to https redirect works but the redirect to `/sweetApp/` does not.

In the end, I would like an external request for `sweetSite.com` to proxy and redirect so the internal server only sees a request for `192.168.3.92:9080/sweetApp/`

I am using Apache 2.4.3 so it should support name based ssl vhosts.

```
#Redirect to SSL
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sweetSite.com
RedirectMatch ^/$ https://sweetSite.com/
</VirtualHost>

# The Real McCoy
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName sweetSite.com

#Map to /sweetApp/ by default
RedirectMatch ^/$ /sweetApp/

SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile ssl/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/certificate.key

#SSL to HTTP Proxy
ProxyPass / http://192.168.3.92:9080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.3.92:9080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me is that if there is a proxyPass rule, it takes precedence over any redirect rule.

Because I need this machine to do both the redirect and the proxy, the only solution I could find was to use mod_rewrite to "proxy" and to change the url to `/sweetApp/`.